# How to call an Apex method with Wrappers parameters from managed package?

Tags: apex, managed-package, wrapper-class, global-methods

I know, how to access to such a method: `packageName.MyGlobalClass.doWork();`
But what if our method gets a Wrapers parameters? Like this:

```
    global with sharing class MyGlobalClass{
        global static void doWork(List<WrapperClass> parameters){
            //some logic is here
        }
        global class WrapperClass{
            @InvocableVariable(required=true label='Id') global ID someId;
            @InvocableVariable(required=true) global String stringValue;
        }
    }
```

How can I get this method? And set to Wrapper my parameter?

Comment: `new packageName.MyGlobalClass.WrapperClass().stringValue = 'Hello'`; ?

Comment: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void WrapperClass() from the type packageName.MyGlobalClass

Comment: is there any parameterized constructor?

Comment: Just a few parametrs like a `stringValue` with labels inside `WrapperClass`.

Comment: Did you replace "packageName" with the package's namespace value?

Comment: yes. But it thinks, that `WrapperClass` is a method. But it's a class. So maybe no `()`?

Comment: For example, I can do such a list: `List<packageName.MyGlobalClass.WrapperClass> wList = new List<packageName.MyGlobalClass.WrapperClass>();`

Comment: The () was to call the constructor. Does `packageName.MyGlobalClass.WrapperClass wrapper = new packageName.MyGlobalClass.WrapperClass();` work? Is it just that you have only got constructors that take parameters?

Comment: It works. I changed the wrapper class in my question, so you can check how it looks like. A few parameters inside `{}`.

Comment: Oh, I got it. `wrapper.stringValue = 'Hello';` Thank you)

Answer (score 0):

To sum up what has been said in comments and close the question, here is the solution:

```
packageName.MyGlobalClass.WrapperClass wrapper = new packageName.MyGlobalClass.WrapperClass();

wrapper.someId = 'someId';
wrapper.stringValue = 'stringValue';

packageName.MyGlobalClass.doWork(new List<packageName.MyGlobalClass.WrapperClass>{
        wrapper
});
```